# Find the first case of a wildcard plus a number and letter using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm writing a macro in Access that pulls data from a file in Excel.  I will know the row the data is housed in, but I won't know the column.

I can determine the column by searching for the first instance of a cell that ends in a number immediately followed by the letter "E".  For instance "02/10E" or "10 15E".

I am able to open the Excel file from Access.  I can also get to the tab where the data is stored.

**How, from Access VBA, can I run a search to find the upper left-most occurrence of a cell in Excel that ends in a number, then a letter?**  I assume I should use a wildcard and then some type of regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses Excel **VBA** and not Access.  We scan along row#5 looking for a cell in which:

- the last character is **E**
- the next-to-last is numeric

.

```
Sub FindTheCell()
    Dim MyRow As Long, v As Variant
    MyRow = 5
    For i = 1 To Columns.Count
        v = Cells(MyRow, i).Value
        If Right(v, 1) = "E" And IsNumeric(Left(Right(v, 2), 1)) Then
            MsgBox "Found the data in column " & i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

As you see, regex is not required.  *This may be adaptable to Access.*